# generate url parameter like ?filter[color]=2&filter[brand]=apple with select dropdown option Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi In my Project I want to filter product by select option, I have some drop-down select option:

first is colors and second is brands and etc.

I use a method that use elequentbuilder. in my scenario
parameters should pass to controller like http://localhost:8000/news/search?filter[color]=red&filter[brand]=apple.

my question is what's best way to implement this scenario
that means when i select color dropdown form submits and shows http://localhost:8000/news/search?filter[color]=red in next request when I select brand from select drop down form submits and shows
http://localhost:8000/news/search?filter[color]=red&filter[brand]=apple and etc 
I'm just looking for a way to generate url like what I said.

Comment: please format your post ! it's unreadable (no paragraph)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at HTML5 JavaScript History API.
With it, you could do something like this to modify the browser url:

```
<a href="javascript:push('http://myshop.com/books/123');">
    Book 123
</a> <br/>
<a href="javascript:push('http://myshop.com/apps/456');">
    App 456
</a>

<script>
function loadUrl(url) {
    console.log("loading data from url: " + url);
}

function push(url) {
    history.pushState(null, null, url);
    loadUrl(url);
}
<script>
```

Taken from [this article.](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5/history-api.html)